What is the expected behaviour of the built-in Laravel encryption?
I'm using the encryption built-into Laravel by casting an attribute as 'encrypted' in a model. My understanding is that the attribute will be encrypted when storing (create and update) and decrypted when retrieved.
When I seed, encrypted attributes are indeed encrypted in the database. And when I dump a model, encrypted attributes are encrypted in the dumped output.
Retrieving the encrypted attribute (by doing $model->attribute) appears to only work in actual code scenarios, and throws a decryption exception when I do so in a test (also database assertion using the decrypted value of the attribute passes when I expect it should fail).
Model creation, dump and attribute retrieval in a controller method:
$setupSaving = $financialGoal->setupSaving()->create([
    'goal_name' => $financialGoal->goal_name,
    'amount' => $validated['amount'],
    'start_date' => $validated['start_date'],
     'transfer_auth_code' => $result['data']['auth_code'], // encrypted attribute 
      'is_authorised' => true,
       'is_active' => true,
]);
dump($setupSaving, $setupSaving->transfer_auth_code);
App\Models\SetupSaving {#15762
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "setup_savings"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:10 [
    "goal_name" => "fake goal"
    "amount" => 15000.0
    "start_date" => "2024-08-06 00:00:00"
    "transfer_auth_code" => "mYjAzODA5N2VhYTM3MmRiMTRjOCIsInRhZyI6IiJ9" //truncated
    "is_authorised" => true
    "is_active" => true
    "financial_goal_id" => "9cb34536-9775-4a75-89e7-b0bd469009fa"
    "id" => "9cb34538-204b-4a37-9051-659bb57e2a93"
    "updated_at" => "2024-08-06 10:49:03"
    "created_at" => "2024-08-06 10:49:03"
  ]
  #original: array:10 [
    "goal_name" => "fake goal"
    "amount" => 15000.0
    "start_date" => "2024-08-06 00:00:00"
    "transfer_auth_code" => "mYjAzODA5N2VhYTM3MmRiMTRjOCIsInRhZyI6IiJ9" //truncated
    "is_authorised" => true
    "is_active" => true
    "financial_goal_id" => "9cb34536-9775-4a75-89e7-b0bd469009fa"
    "id" => "9cb34538-204b-4a37-9051-659bb57e2a93"
    "updated_at" => "2024-08-06 10:49:03"
    "created_at" => "2024-08-06 10:49:03"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: array:7 [
    "amount" => "float"
    "start_date" => "date"
    "next_date" => "date"
    "is_active" => "boolean"
    "is_authorised" => "boolean"
    "loan_repayments" => "json"
    "transfer_auth_code" => "encrypted"
  ]
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  +usesUniqueIds: true
  #hidden: array:1 [
    0 => "transfer_auth_code"
  ]
  #visible: []
  #fillable: array:11 [
    0 => "financial_goal_id"
    1 => "goal_name"
    2 => "transfer_auth_code"
    3 => "amount"
    4 => "start_date"
    5 => "savings_frequency"
    6 => "next_date"
    7 => "is_authorised"
    8 => "is_active"
    9 => "administrator"
    10 => "loan_repayments"
  ]
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}

"12345tyrfdgy6" // retrieved value

Using the stored attribute at a later point also works:
$token = $financialGoal->setupSaving->transfer_auth_code;
dump($token);
"12345tyrfdgy6" // retrieved value used as payload in an API call
 // API response dump
array:3 [
  "status" => "success"
  "message" => "test message"
  "data" => array:9 [
    "status" => "successful"
    "amount" => 15000
    "tx_ref" => "4373cc8426d62d140ae2d9c79b2a77a3cfcb116c897421771146cfbe9a756accc5f90e78bca7a7e2"
    "payment_type" => "card"
    "created_at" => "2024-08-06T09:49:03.974961Z"
    "ip_address" => null
    "processor_response" => "successful"
    "card" => array:4 [
      "reusable" => true
      "exp_year" => "2026"
      "exp_month" => "07"
      "token" => "12345tyrfdgy6" //retrieved attribute used in API call
    ]
    "meta" => array:13 [
      "benefit_id" => null
      "goal_id" => "9cb34536-9775-4a75-89e7-b0bd469009fa"
      "user_id" => "d94e81cb-4028-3b64-aefc-65175842c3fd"
      "setupBenefit_id" => null
      "investment_service_provider_id" => null
      "loan_id" => null
      "loanProvider_id" => null
      "reward_id" => null
      "providerAuth_id" => null
      "rewardProvider" => null
      "transfer_description" => "Savings"
      "bill_type" => null
      "beneficiaries" => array:1 [
        0 => array:6 [
          "id" => "9cb34536-8158-4d76-b9fd-5afbfd669ae6"
          "name" => "Oluwashina, Ekwueme and Olasunkanmi-fasayo"
          "bank_name" => "Saheed, Israel and Akintade"
          "account_name" => "Oluwashina, Ekwueme and Olasunkanmi-fasayo"
          "account_number" => "846928981594103"
          "amount" => 15000
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]

My understanding is that this is the expected behaviour.
The issue then is my test. I get an decryption exception error when I try to retrieve the encrypted attribute like this:
dump($goal->fresh()->setupSaving->transfer_auth_code); // should return decrypted value
expect($goal->fresh()->setupSaving->transfer_auth_code)->toBe('12345tyrfdgy6'); // should fail because I'm comparing unlike strings but not give a decryption exception error
 //Error
that…  DecryptException 
  The payload is invalid.

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php:245
    241▕         // If the payload is not valid JSON or does not have the proper keys set we will
    242▕         // assume it is invalid and bail out of the routine since we will not be able
    243▕         // to decrypt the given value. We'll also check the MAC for this encryption.
    244▕         if (! $this->validPayload($payload)) {
  ➜ 245▕             throw new DecryptException('The payload is invalid.');
    246▕         }
    247▕
    248▕         return $payload;
    249▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php:245
  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php:158

but when I comment these out, my test passes and curiously, the dump of $goal->fresh()->setupSaving shows decrypted value of 'transfer_auth_code' when I would expect it to be encrypted as was the case when I dumped after model creation:
App\Models\SetupSaving {#16989
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "setup_savings"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:14 [
    "id" => "9cb350fb-ec5c-416f-a511-277cbba30803"
    "financial_goal_id" => "9cb350fa-f0e7-41d9-8d7a-7ba0eeb467a3"
    "goal_name" => "fake goal"
    "transfer_auth_code" => "12345tyrfdgy6" // not encrypted
    "amount" => "15000.00"
    "start_date" => "2024-08-06"
    "savings_frequency" => "Monthly"
    "next_date" => "2024-09-06"
    "is_authorised" => 1
    "is_active" => 1
    "administrator" => "SmartWealth"
    "loan_repayments" => "[]"
    "created_at" => "2024-08-06 11:21:57"
    "updated_at" => "2024-08-06 11:21:57"
  ]
  #original: array:14 [
    "id" => "9cb350fb-ec5c-416f-a511-277cbba30803"
    "financial_goal_id" => "9cb350fa-f0e7-41d9-8d7a-7ba0eeb467a3"
    "goal_name" => "fake goal"
    "transfer_auth_code" => "12345tyrfdgy6"
    "amount" => "15000.00"
    "start_date" => "2024-08-06"
    "savings_frequency" => "Monthly"
    "next_date" => "2024-09-06"
    "is_authorised" => 1
    "is_active" => 1
    "administrator" => "SmartWealth"
    "loan_repayments" => "[]"
    "created_at" => "2024-08-06 11:21:57"
    "updated_at" => "2024-08-06 11:21:57"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: array:7 [
    "amount" => "float"
    "start_date" => "date"
    "next_date" => "date"
    "is_active" => "boolean"
    "is_authorised" => "boolean"
    "loan_repayments" => "json"
    "transfer_auth_code" => "encrypted"
  ]
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  +usesUniqueIds: true
  #hidden: array:1 [
    0 => "transfer_auth_code"
  ]
  #visible: []
  #fillable: array:11 [
    0 => "financial_goal_id"
    1 => "goal_name"
    2 => "transfer_auth_code"
    3 => "amount"
    4 => "start_date"
    5 => "savings_frequency"
    6 => "next_date"
    7 => "is_authorised"
    8 => "is_active"
    9 => "administrator"
    10 => "loan_repayments"
  ]
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
} 

It appears that the stored attribute is no longer encrypted at this point when it should be. I expected this assertion to fail but it passes:
$this->assertDatabaseHas('setup_savings', [
    'financial_goal_id' => $goal->id,
    'transfer_auth_code' => '12345tyrfdgy6', // should be encrypted and this should fail but it passes
]);

Is this the expected behaviour or I'm I missing something?
